# Creating a new module in Odoo - Cannot see the module on app list after installation

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I setup and installed Odoo. After installation I did scaffolding to create a test module. Within that module I added some code and the module appeared under my module list. However after installation I do not see the module on my app list. Below is my code:

*button_action_demo.py*

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

#Non-odoo library
import random
from random import randint
import string

class button_action_demo(models.Model):
    _name = 'button.demo'
    name = fields.Char(required=True,default='Click on generate name!')
    password = fields.Char()

    def generate_record_name(self):
        self.ensure_one()
    #Generates a random name between 9 and 15 characters long and writes it to the record.
        self.write({'name': ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(randint(9,15)))})

    def generate_record_password(self):
        self.ensure_one()
    #Generates a random password between 12 and 15 characters long and writes it to the record.
        self.write({
            'password': ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(randint(12,15)))
        })

    def clear_record_data(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        self.write({
            'name': '',
            'password': ''
        })
```

*views.xml*

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_buttons_form">
      <field name="name">Buttons</field>
      <field name="model">button.demo</field>
      <field name="type">form</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <form string="Button record">
        <!--The header tag is built to add buttons within. This puts them at the top -->
        <header>
      <!--The oe_highlight class gives the button a red color when it is saved.
      It is usually used to indicate the expected behaviour. -->
            <button string="Generate name" type="object" name="generate_record_name" class="oe_highlight"/>
      <button string="Generate password" type="object" name="generate_record_password"/>
      <button string="Clear data" type="object" name="clear_record_data"/>
        </header>
        <group>
      <field name="name"/>
      <field name="password"/>
        </group>
    </form>
      </field>
  </record>

  <!--The action -->
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="buttons_example_action">
            <field name="name">Create new record</field>
            <field name="res_model">button.demo</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
            <field name='view_id' ref='view_buttons_form'/>
        </record>

        <!-- top level menu: no parent -->
        <menuitem id="main_button_menu" name="Buttons demo"/>
        <menuitem id="button_menu" name="Buttons demo"
                  parent="main_button_menu"/>
        <menuitem id="menu_detail_logging"
                action="buttons_example_action" parent="button_menu"
                sequence="20"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

***manifest**.py*

```
{
    'name': "button_action_demo",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

*security.py*

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_button_action_demo_button_action_demo,button_action_demo.button_action_demo,model_button_action_demo_button_action_demo,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Can someone please guide me what am I missing on my code. I'm more than happy to share more code if required but I think I have provided most of the bits

Comment: Did you added security file in your module?

Comment: If module is not viewing in app list then it is not in right directory.
It should be in directories which were mentioned in .conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If module is not visible in app list then check few things, listed below.

- Restart your Server.
- Update App list.
- Place module in right addons ***PATH***.

If your ***security*** file is not working well or something wrong with your ***manifest*** file all these things will happen during installation or after installation.

Answer (score 2):

Add security or open debug mood and then click become super user in odoo 13 admin is not super user but you can make him by doing above

Comment: I have tried to see if my security file has any issues and I did not see so

Comment: What will happen after becoming super user? @Muhammad

Comment: You will be able to see it in app list as in odoo 11 you can see all modules in app list as administrator in odoo 13 you have to give full rights if you want normal admin to see these modules or for now became super user that will behave same as admin in odoo11

Comment: But custom module is visible in all modes i.e. non-debug mode or debug mode.

Comment: No not in odoo 13 custom models needs to have access right just become super user and then see if you have acces of that modul if still no access make sure its an app in manifest file

Comment: I am currently working on odoo13 my module still visible to me without activating debug mode.

Comment: There are only few reason if your module is not visible in app list.
->Restart your server. ->Update app list. ->module is not in right directory.

Comment: He said he installed the module means he know how things work in previous versions and restating or updating app list is not the issue you may already have access right in your modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204537/discussion-between-adam-strauss-and-muhammad-yusuf).